# How to approach this complicated optimization problem?

Tags: optimization

I have a 4x4 matrix of constants $A$ and an unknown column vector of the length 4 $B$.

The sum of $B$'s elements is also a given constant $c$.

We multiply $A×B$ and get a resulting column vector $P$ of length 4.

My task is to set optimal element values for $B$, which are all $\in\Bbb N$, so that the product of the elements in $P$ becomes maximal.

Another restriction is that no element of $P$ may become negative.

I know how to multiply matrices or how to convert them into single equation lines. But I have no idea how to optimize the product of the resulting vector's elements.
How should I approach this problem in general?

Comment: In the first place, you can't multiply a $4\times4$ matrix with a row vector (which is a $1\times4$ matrix). In the second place, even if it was a column vector, you wouldn't get a $4\times4$ matrix as the result.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, sorry. I corrected that. The 4x4 was a typo and I like to mix up the row and column words... No idea why. :-/ Now it's correct, I hope.

Comment: Why don't you write out the optimization problem using some mathematical notation?

Comment: Because I'm not familiar with that MathJax (or whatever) syntax... :-( I also don't really know how to describe what I need to optimize mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be solved with standard MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) solvers. The model can look like:

[image]

There are a number of excellent MINLP solvers available (e.g. [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron), [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne), [Bonmin](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin)). You can try them out [online](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html).

Comment: I was rather looking for how to solve it by hand or how to program an algorithm that solves it...

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the question.